# How to add Auto-Increment to all database Tables with Primary key set

Tags: mysql, sql

I use

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `tablename` MODIFY `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

To add Auto increment to a specific table with column name **ID**, However, what I want is to:

1 - Add Auto-Increment to all tables in a particular database (even if there are 1000 tables) with column name **ID**.

2 - Check if primary key is present in each table name with column name **ID** to be able to alter it.

The reason is I have a database with over 2,000 tables and after upgrading my xammp version, it seems to remove the auto-increment but retains primary key value.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: @DaleK done, any ideas.

Comment: It seems very dodgy that upgrading a component removes the auto-increment. I'd report that as a bug.

Comment: @daleK thanks, but I have searched/scoured the stack overflow site yet nothing.

Comment: "seems to remove"  can you show the output of `show create table yourtablename` for one of these tables?

Comment: I would fix the migration...

Comment: @shadow how please elaborate, I have been looking for a solution since an hour

Comment: Warning, REMOVING Primary Key from each table and then ADD auto increment back to the tables will make your data FOREVER useless.  IMHO.

Comment: @chiefo I cannot elaborate as I have no clue what you have done. An in-place mysql upgrade should not remove auto increment as it is a basic feature. A dumpt-then-import will not remove auto increment, unless you modify the dump manually.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a cursor to loop through all tables which has an `ID` column in a specific database. Then use `prepared statement` to execute necessary `alter table` statements. Everything is done in a procedure . It's written and tested in workbench. Please note, based on your illustration, this is assuming all your tables' PK in the database are on column 'ID',which means NO OTHER columns are PK. Additionally, NO OTHER columns are auto_increment.

```
create database testdatabase;
use testdatabase;
drop table if exists t1;
drop table if exists t2;
drop table if exists t3;
create table t1 (id int,num int);
create table t2 (id int primary key, num int);
create table t3 (id int primary key auto_increment, num int);

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists add_pk_ai//
create procedure add_pk_ai(db_name varchar(20),col_name varchar(20),dt_type varchar(20)) -- in parameters include the database name, column name ,and the data type of the column
begin
declare tb_name varchar(20);
declare col_key varchar(20);
declare col_extra varchar(20);
declare done bool default false;
declare c cursor for select table_name,column_key,extra 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema=db_name and column_name=col_name and data_type=dt_type;
declare continue handler for not found set done=true;

open c;
lp:loop
fetch c into tb_name,col_key,col_extra;
if done=true then
leave lp;
end if;

if col_key!='PRI'  then
set @stmt=concat('alter table ',db_name,'.',tb_name,' add primary key (',col_name,');');
prepare stmt1 from @stmt;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
end if;

if col_extra!='auto_increment' then
set @stmt=concat('alter table ',db_name,'.',tb_name,' modify ',col_name,' ',dt_type,' auto_increment ;');
prepare stmt2 from @stmt;
execute stmt2;
deallocate prepare stmt2;
end if;

end loop lp;

end// 
delimiter ;
-- let's test the procedure
call add_pk_ai('testdatabase','id','int'); 

desc t1;
-- result set:
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id, int(11), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
num, int(11), YES, , , 

desc t2;
-- result set:
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id, int(11), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
num, int(11), YES, , , 

desc t3;
-- result set:
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id, int(11), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
num, int(11), YES, , ,
```